# Linear interpolation list with points

Tags: java

I have a method named moveCar which has a timer which calls the car.update() method every 40 ms. The counter gets incremented every 40 ms in the current situation, but the counter should only be incremented when the car is at the end point. Then the counter should be incremented (which means the endpoint is now the next point in the list) and should be moved with lineair interpolation to the next point, this should happen untill the last point is reached. I tried to make a check in the update method that if the car position is equal to the end position that the counter gets incremented but it did not solve the problem, how to do this?

The moveCar method:

```
       public void moveCar() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (startTime == null) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long diff = now - startTime;

                i = (double) diff / (double) playTime;

                car.update(i);                                 
                repaint();

            }
        });
        timer.start();
        }
```

Car update + lerp method:

```
 public void update(double i){

        repaint();

        //counter is 0 by default

        if (counter < Lane.firstLane.size()) {

            startPoint = new Point(carPosition.x, carPosition.y);
            endPoint = new Point(Lane.firstLane.get(counter).x, Lane.firstLane.get(counter).y);

            carPosition.x=(int)lerp(startPoint.x,endPoint.x,i);                  
            carPosition.y=(int)lerp(startPoint.y,endPoint.y,i);                                       

            System.out.println("Car position: x" + carPosition.x + ": y" + carPosition.y);
            repaint();

            counter++;
        }
}



  double lerp(double a, double b, double t) {
            return a + (b - a) * t;
        }
```

Lane.cs

```
         public static List<Point> firstLane = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Point(10,375),new Point(215,385),new Point(230,452)/*,new Point(531,200)*/));
```

Comment: So what *is* the problem? It's hard for me to distinguish the "shoulds" from the actual error description...

Comment: The problem is: the counter gets updated every 40 ms in the current situation, it should only be incremented when the car is at the end position. With incrementing the counter the endPosition is also updated, as you can see in the code.

Comment: I think your `if(...)` in the update method is always true in this case. That's why the counter is always increased. Btw... shrinking down the code to a minimal example would make it easier to provide feedback.

Comment: @Seb any ideas on how to fix the update method, so that the car moves along all the points in the List? I think the code in my OP is the most minimal I can give.

Comment: I don't understand your concept of a Lane in the example and its relation to the counter. Am I right to assume that your if condition in the update method *is supposed to* express something like "not yet at the end of the line"?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your update method is wrong

```
Lane currentLane = ...; // store the current lane somewhere
Lane nextLane = ...; // store the next lane somewhere

public void update(double progress){
    startPoint = new Point(currentLane.x, currentLane.y);
    endPoint = new Point(nextLane.x, nextLane.y);

    carPosition.x=(int)lerp(startPoint.x, endPoint.x, progress);                  
    carPosition.y=(int)lerp(startPoint.y, endPoint.y, progress);                                       

    if (progress >= 1.0) { /// assuming that 0 <= progress <= 1
        currentLane = nextLane;
        nextLane = ...; // switch next lane
    }
}
```

I removed the repaint() calls... I guess you need to include them in appropriate locations. My code does not work for the first Lane (or the last, depending on your implementation). I still don't quite get the problem, so it is hard to fix. :)

Comment: I don't really understand your solution. You have a nextLane declared but the car has to stay on one lane (maybe I implement multiple lanes later on) which exists of multiple points. I also don't see a counter in your example. The counter needs to point to a point in the Lane list.